# C - проверка ввода на символ

Tags: c, input, while, printf

собственно проблема: В devC все компилируется как должно. В других компиляторах, просто бесконечно пишет Wrong Format! Хотя, с другими условиями проверки все нормально.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    double x;
    do{
        printf("input x:");
        scanf("%lf",&x);
        if(x<0 || fmod(x,90) == 0 || x > DBL_MAX || isalpha(x) == 1){
            printf("Wrong Format!Try again!\n");
            continue;
        }
    } while(x<0 || fmod(x,90) == 0 || x > DBL_MAX || isalpha(x) == 1);
    printf("The maximum value is - %g", DBL_MAX);
}
```

Comment: Те же яйца! Этим способом тоже пользовался

Comment: В каких именно компиляторах не работает?

Comment: Тут написана всякая лажа, у `scanf` надо проверять возвращаемое значение, `x > DBL_MAX` не может быть true для нормальных значений, `isalpha` принимает на вход код символа и т.п.

Comment: Лажа? А как вы по другому область определения функции проверите? Тут просто нет формулы по которой дальше считается. В данном случае область определения от одного до плюс бесконечности с выпадающими 1.2пи, пи, и так далее до бесконечности

Comment: x > DBL_MAX. В данном случае определяет макс значение вводимого числа

Comment: В этом, допустим https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler